# adjustment based on k neighbors

Tags: variance, k-nearest-neighbour

I am using a nearest neighbor approach based on features to pick the most similar `neighbor-tickers` in order to predict the `performance` of `target-ticker`.  My `target-ticker` has certain features and I'm picking `neighbor-tickers` based on a smallest euclidean distance between the features of `neighbor-ticker` and `target-ticker`.  I am picking `k` neighbors and at present I am weighting all features equally.

To evaluate how important my features are in my prediction of the `target-ticker`, I'm taking either the `squared` or `absolute value` of the error between the average of `neighbor-tickers` and `target-tickers` `performance`. Explicity, this is `error = target-ticker_performance - average(neighbor-tickers_performance)`.

Now across many `target-tickers`, looking at the sum of squared errors `SSE` and sum of absolute errors `SAE` gives me an indication of how well my `neighbor-tickers` are predicting the `target-ticker`, or really, how well my features are allowing me to pick better performing `neighbor-tickers`.

Now I'm trying to determine the optimal number of neighbors `k`:

As a sanity check, I decided to run the process with features that I believe have no relationship to `performance`, and as I increase `k`, the `SSE` and `SAE` decline in a non-linear manner.  Based on this, it appears that I need an adjustment to my errors based on `k`. I think the adjustment would be in some way related to the distribution of my underlying `population's` `performance` from which my `neighbor` samples are drawn. For example, the distribution of `performance` in my `population` is very right skewed.

Any ideas for how to adjust my errors based on the number of `neighbors`, `k`, in my sample?

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure that SSE decreases linearly with *k*? This would mean that the smallest error is obtained for *k=n-1*, i.e. when all target-tickers are classified to the total average. If this is the case, your entire apporach does not seem to work.

Comment: @cdalitz  I have edited the question.  It is a `non-linear` relationship.  Again - for features that have no relationship to performance, as k increases -> my SSE decreases.  This leads me to believe I should be adjusting my SSE in some way by k and perhaps the distribution of performance in the underlying population from which neighbors are drawn.

Comment: If the features are meaningless (without predictive usefulness), the smallest SSE should be obtained by assigning the toal mean to each value, because the mean *m* has the property that it minimizes the SSE. I would thus expect that the smallest SSE is obtianed for *k=n*.

Comment: I agree- because of this I'd like to adjust the SSE such that it's not `k` that is determining my SSE, but the neighbors themselves.  For example an adjustment such that for meaningless features, SSE_k=i = SSE_k=n for all i...  This way when I use meaningful features it is purely the features that produces SSE, and not being confounded because, say for example k is large.